# Strange behaviour from "Approval workflow"-task in SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

Im trying to migrate/move a Workflow that is built upon the standard "Approval WF". Im moing it from SP2013 Onprem to SP Online.

The approver gets an email and can see the document, although it does not contain the link to the task, nor any button in MS Word to approve/reject.

But my biggest concern is:
When the approver go to the Task-list in SP he can see the task, it is set at "Not started", but the buttons(se picture) confuses me. I was expecting an[Approve] and [Reject]-button. What am I

[image: RequestChangeReassignTask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know exactly what of the below stuff that finally made it but, this worked for me :

1. Make sure publishing feature is activated on site
2. Make sure that your approver(s) are in the Approvers-permission
   group for list (youll get the Approvers group once publishing
   features is activated)
3. When you associate/connect the workflow to your list, make sure to
   change the task list (dropdown) from "Tasks" to "Workflow Tasks"
4. In the final step of the association you'll get a Association form,
   make sure that the bottom checkbox (Activate approver of content) is
   checked.
5. And most important of all, have fun!